# Handlebars getting object value at helper, without compile with data

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

```
    <h1>Handlebars JS Example</h1>
<script id="some-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template"> <table>
   {{helper yes}}
</script>
var source = $("#some-template").html(); 
var template = Handlebars.compile(source); 

var data = { 
    yes:'Yes'
}; 

Handlebars.registerHelper('helper', function(person) {
console.log(person);
console.log(data);
console.log(data[person]);
console.log(myFunction(person));
});
$('body').append(template(data));

function myFunction(keyname) {
  return data[keyname];
};
```

I try to get value of data by string that i get from handlebars.
[Why no methods that i tried works?](http://jsfiddle.net/a9wjbsch/377/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now i truly found solution, the problem was that when template is compiled we can put object to it like on my example up. But i needed to get it from var and look for it by name. So when i use argument like up, its still says that cannot found property yes. I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29105127/5102892) that as argument we can use string. And its work, my code will be cleaner.  [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a9wjbsch/379/)

```
    var source = $("#some-template").html(); 
var template = Handlebars.compile(source); 

var data = { 
    yes:'Yes'
}; 

    <h1>Handlebars JS Example</h1>
    <script id="some-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
       {{helper 'yes'}}
    </script>

    Handlebars.registerHelper('helper', function(person) {
    return data[person];
    });
    $('body').append(template());
```